# getJSON - How to print out the result, and how to retrieve input?

Tags: javascript, java, html, json

I implemented some java functions. Now I have to present the result to the user via html.

```
public Object post()
{
    responseHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    try
    {
        final User user = UC0_Login.getLoggedInUser(this);
        List<Measurement> mylist =  MeasurementService.getMeasurementsbyPatient(user.getUsername().toString());
        for(int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
             Measurement mesPatient = mylist.get(i);
             DownloaderService.saveTxt(mesPatient);
            // System.out.println("Test Name:      " + mesPatient.getRequest().getPatient().getFirst_name().toString());
         }

    }
    catch(HttpException x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
        this.statusCode = x.getStatusCode();
        return "{ \"success\": false }";
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
        this.statusCode = StatusCode.SERVER_ERROR_500;
        return "{ \"success\": false }";
    }
    String property = "java.io.tmpdir";
    String tempDir = System.getProperty(property);
    String result = "Your measurements have been saved at" + tempDir;

    return result;
}
```

There I implemented post(), in a Java class. I also created a HttpServer in the background. As shown in the code, I return a String. How can I print out that string in HTML? And how can I get input (for example an integer) from HTML into for example a get() function? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are basically looking for AJAX request and response, here is a good source to learn how to.

https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/#posting

For example,

HTML

```
<p id="result"></p>

<form id="frm1" action="/action_page.php">
  Your input: <input type="text" id="myInput"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'Your URL Goes Here');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response;
    }
    else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send(encodeURI('input=' + input)); // Use your API param keys here
```